# Laravel 5.3 group routing not working

Tags: laravel

I want to route grouped by prefix but the following code not working. The second two routes says page not found.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function (){

Route::get('/', function (){

    return "m";

});

Route::get('a', function (){

    return "a";

});

Route::get('b', function (){

    return "b";

});

});

example.com/admin works
example.com/admin/a
and
example.com/admin/b
not working.
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you try it by removing prefix group and adding `admin` to each route? It is to just check if the problem is with route group or not.

Comment: Just tried and seems to be working. Can you please check if those 2 routes have conflicts with any other routes?

Comment: Try adding a / to the routes inside the group. Like `/a`

Comment: Works for me. The problem must be somewhere else. Maybe a problem with Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Solved

/ was not the fact. There were another route like this (above the group route)

```
example.com/admin/{param}
```

which creates a confliction.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
        Route::get('/a', function () {
        return view('a');
    });
});
```

Comment: A preceding `/` is not necessary in Laravel routes, except for root (i.e. `Route::get('/');`).